# Filestack Video Upload

Tags: javascript, ios, file-upload, fetch

I'm trying to upload video files to filestackapi but every time I do it from the cameraroll on the iPhone simulator I only end up getting a jpg of the video instead of the entire video.

This code does not work:

```
export const uploadToFileStack = (filePath, mimetype, name) => {
  const upload = {
    uri: 'assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=3F50F7F6-1B6A-4DF5-8CE3-EA44B58AC8C5&ext=mov',
    type: 'video/quicktime',
    name: 'default.mov',
  }
  const body = new FormData()
  body.append('fileUpload', upload)
  return fetch('https://www.filestackapi.com/api/store/S3?key=AVyls64bZTVuBwKYNAkM4z', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: body
  })
}
```

This code does work:

```
export const uploadToFileStack = (filePath, mimetype, name) => {
  const upload = {
    uri: '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/34A9C5C3-7B16-46E7-AF3C-CEE91071F641/Documents/C98A7D99-1FA8-43C5-80F8-F056FBCC4E5B.mov',
    type: 'video/quicktime',
    name: 'default.mov',
  }
  const body = new FormData()
  body.append('fileUpload', upload)
  return fetch('https://www.filestackapi.com/api/store/S3?key=AVyls64bRTVuBuKYNAka4z', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: body
  })
```

Working in react native.

Comment: If you have a code that works, then what's your question?

Comment: The code that works is the path of the file right after taking it from the camera but the path that doesn't work is the one from the camera roll, which is what I need to work.

Comment: This guy gave the right answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586631/uploading-videos-using-formdata-in-react-native